# Nested for loop in handling files - java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I want to write for inside for in java 8:

```
for (String file : files) {
                for (String line : lines) {
                    if (file.contains(line)) {
                       //do something
                    }
                }
            }
```

I don't want to write for each inside for each like:

```
files.stream().forEach(file -> { 
      lines.stream().forEach(line-> {
        //do something
      })
})
```

is there anything like

```
(file, line) -> { //do something}
```

and inside the pair I will get all possible permutations

Comment: *and inside the pair I will get all possible permutations* No. There is nothing like that.

Comment: You might find StreamEx's [`ofLines`](https://static.javadoc.io/one.util/streamex/0.6.6/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#ofLines-java.nio.file.Path-) method useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could something like this, but it isn't much different from what you already have in place

```
 files.stream()
      .flatMap(file -> lines.stream().map(line -> new Pair(file, line)))
      .map(pair -> do something with pair)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply defined a class that will hold one of the list to do the research in a method taking a `String`. I used a `Dictionary` class for the example here to find every "word" define in another list.

```
public class Dictionary{

    private List<String> list;

    public Dictionary(List<String> list){
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void printMatch(String word){
        list.stream().filter(word::contains).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Then, for each `file`, just call the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dictionary d = new Dictionary(Arrays.asList("abc", "def", "fgh"));
    Stream.of("def", "ijk").forEach(d::printMatch);
}
```

The example is not suppose to match the actual requirement but to show a simple solution to not use inner loops directly (simply by hiding them in a method ;) ).